# What does ... do in java?

Tags: java

Given the following methode signature, what does the **...** syntax mean?

```
void acceptAll(Object... all);
```

i've googled for it, but couldn't find a good explanation for this strange syntax. Can someone give a KISS explanation and a short example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [Variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function), which means it can take a *variable number* of **arguments** (hence the other name, a [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) function). In the body, the variable indicated by `...` is treated like an array.

Answer (score 3):

These are called the variable arguments or multiple arguments.
With this syntax it means the acceptAll methods accept multiple arguments of type Object.

Check Oracle docs here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html